# Are the raised dot plastic wall tiles really Braille?

Tags: arrowverse, the-flash

In *Flash*, 100th episode, S05E08, *What's Past is Prologe*, there are several shots of Barry and Nora Allen/Flash and Excess in a small room. The walls appear to be plastic tiles with a series of random raised white dots. It reminds me of braille.
Can anyone read the wall?
Is it some sort of message from the writers? or,
Is there any significance for it?
[image: possible braille wall]

Comment: See [this post on SFF.SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/125186/80867) for an explanation as to why this is (almost certainly) not Braille.

Comment: Thank you @RDFozz your link states that the "dots" move and transform, which highly suggests that they are "special effects".

Comment: And this room exists from season 1

Comment: @AnkitSharma I didn't remember that.  Guess I've got another show to binge-watch!

Comment: It's the same secret room of  Harrison Wells/REverse Flash

Comment: Don't have time for further research, but if it's not Braille, it could be binary.

Comment: @Gnemlock You're a genius! That's absolutely brilliant!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## They don't appear to be.

There is a big(ish) article on bustle about it, after scanning through this i found what i think is the most important part.

> If you Google the Braille alphabet and try to read along, you'll discover a problem that I ran across as well. **Some of the more distinguishable symbols do not appear**. They just aren't letters. At first I thought they were placed on the wall upside-down or printed backwards. That would be embarrassing for old Dr. Wells. Then I remembered to check Second Grade Braille. This is your cool lesson of the day. Braille has a system of contractions in addition to the alphabet. Certain symbols can mean letters, prefixes, suffixes, or common words. So, those symbols that I wasn't able to identify are Second Grade symbols. However, with a poor idea of where sentences and words start on the wall, I still wasn't able to decipher anything meaningful. Two symbols that appear next to each other a lot could mean "-ed as" or "-ed z." Deep stuff.
> <sub><sup>*- [Is Harrison Wells Lair covered in Braille? - Bustle](https://www.bustle.com/articles/44093-is-harrison-wells-lair-covered-in-braille-on-the-flash-it-just-could-be-symbolism-but)*</sup></sub>

Later the article says that there is definitely some meaning but we cant be sure of what it is.

> Of course, I could be accidentally insulting The Flash's art department. Perhaps this is supposed to mimic Braille, but doesn't actually say anything and I'm just being an over-analytical jerk. They could have put a panel in upside-down for all we know. Maybe it's not Braille at all. But it definitely is some sort of pattern that's too significant to ignore.
> <sub><sup>*- [Is Harrison Wells' Lair covered in Braille? - Bustle](https://www.bustle.com/articles/44093-is-harrison-wells-lair-covered-in-braille-on-the-flash-it-just-could-be-symbolism-but)*</sup></sub>